# Change appearance of cited URL in bibliography part

Tags: bibtex, citing

In my document the appearance of an URL citation looks incorrect:
[image]

The comma, dot after the URL seems to be wrong there. How can I remove it or is there an even better way to cite an URL?

Short snipped out of my tex:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,11pt,a4paper, twoside,BCOR=2cm,DIV=11,listof=totoc]{scrbook} 
\usepackage{bibgerm}
\usepackage{cite}
\bibliographystyle{alphadin}

@misc{struts,
  title = {GitHub - apache/struts: Mirror of Apache Struts},
  howpublished = {\url{https://github.com/apache/struts}},
  note = {01.01.1990}
}
```

Comment: Add `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}` before  `begin{document}`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That did not change the apperance. I even tried to compile it without the \url{...}. But the comma-dot stayed there.

Comment: maybe try `howpublished={online}, url={http...}`

Comment: thanks! That works like a charm. I do not even need to fill the `howpublished` field.